# Generating time series with copula

Tags: r, time-series, random-generation, copula

I want to generate univariate time series in R using copulas.

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_N,\ldots$ denote random variables such that joint distribution of $X_t$ and $X_{t-1}$ is $C(F(X_t), F(X_{t-1}))$, where $F$ denotes a marginal distribution function, and $C$ a copula.

I am a beginner in R, and at present I face some difficulties understanding the syntax.

I think I should generate a first observation, then with the first observation use the conditional cdf and generate second observation, and so on. 
But I don't understand how to construct the conditional distribution (the function `ccopula` from the copula package is not working properly). I would be glad for any help.

Comment: I cannot install copula, so cannot tell what the issue is but indeed the notion is to use the conditional for $X_t$ given $X_{t-1}$ derived from the copula: compute $u_{t-1}=F(x_{t-1})$, generate $u_t|u_{t-1}$ from the copula, computer $x_t=F^{-1}(u_t)$.

Comment: Why do you think `ccopula` isn't working properly?

Comment: See http://www2.ime.unicamp.br/sinape/sites/default/files/Pumi_Lopes.pdf